# How to list the most fragmented files on Windows 7

Tags: software-rec, defragment

defrag on previous Windows versions produced a report with the list of the most fragmented files. Often a few files are responsible for most of the fragmentation,allowing me to delete/move such files and greatly speed up defragmentation. I can't find anything like that on Windows 7. Can you recommend a similar tool?

Comment: I run SSD and it's fragmented

Comment: no that wasnt my question, but it's helpful to know. By the way, I have a file with 4000 fragments, do you think it has an impact on the MFT size and performance ?

Comment: @Tetsujin: You're insisting that physical read latency is the only part of the story, but I think you're completely ignoring other layers, such as whether the OS will need to spend (noticeably) more CPU time issuing many small reads vs fewer large reads; whether the disk will take the same amount of time handling e.g. a hundred 1MB requests vs ten 10MB requests (especially for SATA SSDs with short queue); and so on.

Comment: I never insisted anything about physical file read latency. I'm worried about the MFT size and traversing time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[The free version of Defraggler does it](https://www.ccleaner.com/defraggler). Comments on the lack of usefullness of defragmentation of SSDs duly noted

Comment: fragments come from the MFT and many fragments will bloat the MFT will they not ?

Comment: would you care to explain why ? I believe NTFS is quite old too but still in use

Comment: The disk format has a lot to do with the MFT and you havent even begun to answer my questions about the MFT

Comment: you are dogmatic https://www.hanselman.com/blog/therealandcompletestorydoeswindowsdefragmentyourssd.aspx